# File upload error in Python CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, file-upload, cgi

I am working on a web interface to a data server that allows users in my office to upload files for storage. Right now I am running a [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html) on my **32-bit Windows XP** desktop with **Python 2.7** and performing some tests with various files (typically images and video files).

For most files, everything seems to work fine. However, when I upload files of around **4MB** or larger the request fails with the server throwing a `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`error.

This is the full traceback in case it is of use, but I suspect not:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)    
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
  self.handle()
File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 337, in handle
  self.handle_one_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 325, in handle_one_request
  method()
File "C:\Python27\lib\CGIHTTPServer.py", line 61, in do_POST
  self.run_cgi()
File "C:\Python27\lib\CGIHTTPServer.py", line 287, in run_cgi
  stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 740, in communicate
  return self._communicate(input)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 960, in _communicate
  self.stdin.write(input)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

At first I suspected a code bug but the server crashes before any of my code is called so I am a confused as to where to look for a solution.

Is it possible that this basic implementation of the server cannot handle larger files? I have looked online and did not find an indication that this is the case. I would have also expected a different error message if this was the case.